# Split column to multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am going to split one column of my table to multiple columns. The fields are separated by comma and I used the split_part. The problem that I faced is the length of string are not same and after splitting they are located from column 1 to column N.

```
Column

a,b,c,d,e,f

b,c,e,f

c,d,e,f
```

my output is:

```
col1   col2  col3 col4 col5 col6

 a      b     c    d    e   f

 b      c     e    f

 c      d     e    f
```

but I want to have an output like this

```
 col1   col2  col3 col4 col5 col6


  a      b     c    d    e   f

         b     c         e   f

               c    d    e   f
```

Comment: How do you know that the value "c" should go into the third column? What if each row hat completely different characters? e.g. `a,x,q,u,m` and `z,w,p,b,e,y,a,v,h,i,k`

Comment: the first row is complete and the second and third row have same fields with some missing values, for example in second row the a and b fields are missing. col1 to col6 refer to fields a to f values, so fields a should be located in col1, fields b in col2, ..., and field f in col6.

Comment: If you just look at a line containing `z,u,h,a` - how would you know which letter belongs to which column?

Comment: In my main data I have 6 fields that are review, benefit, title, location, price, owner that I renamed as a,b,c,d,e and f. So every field has tag and I know which letter belongs to which column. But my problem is they fill the columns from right to left while I have missing values in some row

Comment: What is the maximum number of columns?

Comment: @AliFathalian "*every field has tag*" - then please show example data with such tags, if you want to use the tags to assign the values to their respective column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE split_column (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    col text NOT NULL
)
```

And this data:

```
INSERT INTO split_column (id, col) VALUES
    (1, 'a,b,c,d,e,f'),
    (2, 'b,c,e,f'),
    (3, 'c,d,e,f')
```

The first row contains all values:

```
SELECT string_to_array(col, ',') AS values
FROM split_column
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

| values |
| --- |
| {a,b,c,d,e,f} |

We use it to create a mapping from `col1..colN` to the values:

```
WITH complete AS (
    SELECT string_to_array(col, ',') AS values
    FROM split_column
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
)
SELECT 'col' || value.ordinality AS key, value
FROM complete, unnest(complete.values) WITH ORDINALITY AS value
```

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | a |
| col2 | b |
| col3 | c |
| col4 | d |
| col5 | e |
| col6 | f |

We aggregate the rows to JSON objects:

```
WITH complete AS (
    SELECT string_to_array(col, ',') AS values
    FROM split_column
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
), map AS (
    SELECT 'col' || value.ordinality AS key, value
    FROM complete, unnest(complete.values) WITH ORDINALITY AS value
)
SELECT id, jsonb_object_agg(map.key, map.value) AS object
FROM split_column, string_to_table(col, ',') AS col
JOIN map
    ON col = map.value
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

| id | object |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"col1": "a", "col2": "b", "col3": "c", "col4": "d", "col5": "e", "col6": "f"} |
| 2 | {"col2": "b", "col3": "c", "col5": "e", "col6": "f"} |
| 3 | {"col3": "c", "col4": "d", "col5": "e", "col6": "f"} |

And then we "destructure" them back into records:

```
WITH complete AS (
    SELECT string_to_array(col, ',') AS values
    FROM split_column
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
), map AS (
    SELECT 'col' || value.ordinality AS key, value
    FROM complete, unnest(complete.values) WITH ORDINALITY AS value
), agg AS (
    SELECT id, jsonb_object_agg(map.key, map.value) AS object
    FROM split_column, string_to_table(col, ',') AS col
    JOIN map
        ON col = map.value
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT agg.id, cols.*
FROM agg, jsonb_to_record(agg.object) AS cols(col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, col5 text, col6 text)
ORDER BY id
```

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| 2 |  | b | c |  | e | f |
| 3 |  |  | c | d | e | f |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9807f2556f396f9d954fdfcf0143a1cd)

Comment: Thanks xehpuk! I have another question. If the string is like : 1  {"col1":{a}, "col2":{b}, "col3":{c}, "col4":{d}, "col5":{e}, "col6":{f}}    2  {"col2":{b}, "col3":{c}, "col5":{e}, "col6":{f}}  3  {"col3":{c}, "col4":{d}, "col5":{e}, "col6":{f}}  how we can separated?

Answer (score 1):

Table and data def shamelessly stolen from @xehpuk

```
CREATE TABLE split_column (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    col text NOT NULL
)
```

data

```
INSERT INTO split_column (id, col) VALUES
    (1, 'a,b,c,d,e,f'),
    (2, 'b,c,e,f'),
    (3, 'c,d,e,f')
```

Use Case statements in query:

```
select case when position('a' in col)::bool then 'a' end as col1,
       case when position('b' in col)::bool then 'b' end as col2,
       case when position('c' in col)::bool then 'c' end as col3,
       case when position('d' in col)::bool then 'd' end as col4,
       case when position('e' in col)::bool then 'e' end as col5,
       case when position('f' in col)::bool then 'f' end as col6
  from aaa.split_column
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| null | b | c | null | e | f |
| null | null | c | d | e | f |